# One SQL query to show parent records and their child records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I've got a Tree structure which looks like below

```
Table1
- Iron
 + Land Vehicle
 + Water Vehicle
 + Air Craft 

Select * from Table1 Where Type = 'Vehicle'
```

would give the below as its result.

```
Land Vehicle
Water Vehicle
Air Craft
```

But the actual structure when expanded look like below,

```
Table1
- Vehicle
 - Land Vehicle
     Car
     Van
     Bus
 - Water Vehicle
     Boat
     Ship
 - Air Craft 
     Jet
     Helicopter
```

database table for the above looks like,

```
Item             Type

King Bed          Bed
Double Bed        Bed
Steel D/Bed    Double Bed
Land Vehicle    Vehicle
Car           Land Vehicle 
Van           Land Vehicle 
Bus           Land Vehicle
Water Vehicle   Vehicle
Boat          Water Vehicle 
Ship          Water Vehicle 
Air Craft       Vehicle
Jet            Air Craft
Helicopter     Air Craft 
Arm Chair       Chair
```

Result should be all Vehicles, and the result should look like below.

```
Land Vehicle   
Car           
Van           
Bus          
Water Vehicle   
Boat          
Ship          
Air Craft      
Jet           
Helicopter
```

Basically what the required Query needs to do is select everything that's of type Vehicle and then take the result set as the search criteria and select again. for example if there were three Types of vehicles the next step should be to take those three one by one and check if there's anything underneath those three. if there are take those one by one and search again until the tree structure ends.

Comment: I think you need to reformat the item type section for readability, currently it is difficult to see what format your table is in. Also please provide details of the table such as field names.

Comment: I know.. I want to, but I dont really know how to do it.

Comment: putting 4 spaces before the section will indent it, press enter and put 4 spaces before each entry.

Comment: Hmm, didn't you ask this question yesterday? (Or was it someone else in same class?)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(type)
from table1
where type like '%Vehicle%'
or type like '%Craft%';
```

Something like this should work however I would work on your table design. Type should just say 'vehicle', 'bed', 'chair' etc and another field e.g. Type2 should then have 'land', 'air', 'water', 'furniture' or something like that.

Personally I would have Type1 as 'Furniture' and Type2 would identify it as 'chair'.

after your recent comment:

```
select item, distinct(type)
from table1
where type like '%Vehicle%'
where type like '%Craft%';
```

Comment: Hello, the table is set, As I've given. Basically what we only know is that we need to find all types of vehicles. So

select distinct(type)
from table1
where type like '%Vehicle%'

will only give the three patent types of vehicles.
Also I've only shown a similar example table. the real table has 50k + rows

Comment: then perhaps    select distinct(type), item

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected row. (E.g. `SELECT DISTINCT (c1), c2...` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2...` which is the same as `SELECT DISTINCT c1, (c2)...`.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sanjaya Weerakkody,

Given the data model (poor) design its not easy to find a efficient way to do what you want.
You can apply something like this;

```
with Category AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT [Type] as label, [Type]
FROM table1 WHERE [Type] like '%Vehicle%' OR [Type] like '%Air Craft%')
, 
Aux as
(
    SELECT 0 as auxToOrder,  label, [type] FROM Category
    UNION
    SELECT 1 as auxToOrder , item, [type] FROM Table1 WHERE [Type] like '%Vehicle%' OR [Type] like '%Air Craft%'

)

select auxToOrder, [type], label 
from Aux
Order by [type], auxToOrder
```

RESULT

```
auxToOrder    type    label
0    Air Craft    Air Craft
1    Air Craft    Helicopter
1    Air Craft    Jet
0    Land Vehicle    Land Vehicle
1    Land Vehicle    Bus
1    Land Vehicle    Car
1    Land Vehicle    Van
0    Vehicle    Vehicle
1    Vehicle    Air Craft
1    Vehicle    Land Vehicle
1    Vehicle    Water Vehicle
0    Water Vehicle    Water Vehicle
1    Water Vehicle    Boat
1    Water Vehicle    Ship
```

Comment: Basically what the Query needs to do is select everything that's of type Vehicle and then take the result set as the search criteria and select again. for example if there were three Types of vehicles the next step should be to take those three one by one and check if there's anything underneath that. if there are take those one by one and search again until the tree structure ends.

Comment: This does not give the desired answer